# What number should be added div:nth-child (WordPress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css-selectors

I need to add style into the class="green".
I trired the following code but it doesn't add the style.
Would you please let me know how to sove this?

```
<body class="page-template">
     <nav>
          <div class="red">
                 <div class="blue">
                 </div>
          </div>
     </nav>
     <div class="green">
     </div>
</body>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery(".page-template div:nth-child(3)").attr("style","z-index: 90000000;");
jQuery(".page-template div:nth-of-type(3)").attr("style","z-index: 90000000;");
```

(*When I change the number to 1, it adds style to the class="red")
Thank you.

Comment: Its working [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jahuwso0/) .

Comment: please try this  jQuery(".page-template div.green").attr("style","z-index: 90000000;");

Comment: Hi Swati: thank you for your help. Oh.. that's strange, when I do it, it just doesn't change, it only work with (1). I also tried jQuery(".page-template div.green").attr("style", "z-index: 90000000;");  , but still it doesn't add the style. What would be the potential problems?

Comment: Are you seeing any error inside your browser console ?

Comment: Hi Swati: I checked but no error... https://i.imgur.com/KhbwfnM.jpg  /  https://i.imgur.com/4GPKjLa.jpg

Comment: @Janki:thank you for your advice. I tired the code but still it doesn't change. i.imgur.com/4GPKjLa.jpg //  i.imgur.com/KhbwfnM.jpg

Comment: Can't you just write click event and use $('this') as selector

Comment: @Rush.2707: ummm... sorry, I'm a newbie, very clumsy.. Would you please let me know how to deal with $('this'), if possible?

Comment: have you tried with !important also ?

Comment: @Janki: yeah, I tried like this => jQuery(".page-template div.pp-offcanvas-container").attr("style", "z-index: 90000000!important;");   , but still it doesn't add it...

Comment: @Fioi if you sure you want to add style with class="green" div element then it should work with this  jQuery(".page-template div.green").attr("style", "z-index: 90000000  !important;");

Comment: otherwise your jQuery is not invoking

Comment: Hi Janki: yeah, I tried your code, but it doesn't add the style. I test jQuery with other codes and it works well, only this code doesn't work...

Comment: can you please share your website URL? if possible

Comment: you are having issue with submenu right?

Comment: Good Morning Janki: I'm having issue with this part => https://i.imgur.com/KhbwfnM.jpg

Comment: @Janki: hi Janki, I decided to skip this part, thank you for your help, have a nice weekend : )